# Cannot download proper file from google server to my server

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

I am trying to download a file from google server to my server. But the file downloaded is corrupted. While googling I found that the responce is a raw file. I followed the coding listed below:

```
$getUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' . $file_id.'?alt=media';
    $authHeader = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $oAuthToken;


        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $getUrl);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            $authHeader
        ]);


        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

$file = $_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'invoice'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'user_' . $user_id .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'receipts'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $file_name;

    file_put_contents($file ,// where to save file
$data);
```

The Output which I am getting in data is:

```
Data Loaded: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2Upo0zPUHctSPxMvqYuBkIwhKUEWIGHQdbhsDAqbfdy_a6-0LW1L1OqZ4xFtu3OyZiSJOAoRWr2wcbV5LTyELTPK8GcI-g

Content-Type: image/jpeg

Content-Disposition: attachment

ETag: "pvTNHKA6KkAgXTpZXMwU4P67ELo/NDg5OTU3NzE5"

Vary: Origin

Vary: X-Origin

Expires: Tue, 03 Nov 2015 10:00:12 GMT

Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2015 10:00:12 GMT

Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate

Content-Length: 36410

X-Goog-Hash: crc32c=vzEAxg==

Server: UploadServer

Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1

Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; p="1"; ma=604800



����JFIF��C    !"$"$��C����"��   
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�  
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������    
���w!1AQaq"2�B����   #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?�f���J���rd��4yF@5���Wm�    ����Gfw�\��]N�s�ןiW��]F�t2k��Rg�J���]�*9���\k��n����ֺk��9�>P�؝ͩ@jϻ��*�y�������:UӋl�J�$M�֍���ԭ��g�(x�ur�Q�lն�*jڶk.��]��VsGu)_BW5
ϊYX�N��51՝�7!xy<U�ǋ�1ަx���j�BL]�+�ë2W;��U���������dWCit�kG�k?J�984�P��g��/��;X{��@*��7��'�\u�k6K�/�������\(�5Bk���'Pԕs�~��]j�y���u�N�xvξ�TP��*u�ޮ/�BWo�����.sY}`��iw�Ei[HN+�ҧ,�&�+)tS�s��Sj.V� ��6�V8a]Qw8�7����Em�a��n��<W-�C�Ċ$�T��%�Ur�zVI����%�b�W#$8�����W����Fŝ9K0⺭&,Y5���i�g�+nT�   �rf��eG�Gҟah02+C�
:TXW�Sn�L  n*��g�5�U��&�[䊎E�rG\⡛n��6$d���X�73Z��6�����+sY4m�=H�y���H3��k��g�9�B�R��ڳs�Щ�:MCPTBs�ư��7?Z�/�K�_��M��F �k>{�Nd;�\�؟5���O�չ�<�/���
t�JgE ���4��}i3L.��L�`����)ƚzQa\a
��*&�E��m�L9��ZcQ`�Êa=��j2iX@M4�z?:����He�ʽ��x����0V��������篭��
�/��<
�����f��    ��Z2�Vm�S]A�����T4l�th��sS���r�8AA�4V�x����   S�<U    F�+
��ʢZ��ha�J
4U��=�d5vӖ�QJ�d�?5] Z����4��-aiQ�a]~�k�(�y��#����)Yf�=:f$sYKg��l�+ƨ��F��4u'�kKp�s�`(5��@�v�馮s՝�����Ҩ\�`��b���H��[H��*�3�Hpy�Bc�ڦ�O,�O;��N���T�$�Q�4�!r櫙�Ԋ��
��Z�0������u��Y0�rj����U�(��(�#��;�NMUb��~5�e����^9��}��H-�Z�>>��2�ƺ�9���=��'ף���k��'���x���Ү7�Y�~2���n}�'3��ot{Uψ�/����L�#]�    >��⩦m���Z~��w;���Z�g|0���%�`N�JI���]R"1�.�h5�)Hθc�wq\oSh�06lܖ��r8�j�_�6vr�l�c�C��Y�!��$
%��
 T��~&�l'$zΗ�؛�n.���N�^k��o��-c���9�q��*~��f�����c�L��[��n|.���}.�   m���[�ڶ�Q#��rZ�PZ�ۜ�z�]��;-�A<���ǿu˽R�M��-g�c�c����N�~��TI�6�&mr�������݅vG��    �-Q�5�a�r�'��s�BG#ھ.��5�&��u�P�$�<�v��ǜc�һ-�w�4�{u�|Cv�|a��F۞rO<���qQl�Xi${��b��u�'ֺM7R��-���_��   R� :>a�,Tp�)��*�=�k�.�$���ZM�
�i�`q�U
*�2oٲ}��cғZ� qK2zT�09�HE$;��k6�R��ҽ=qY��բyH����S̀i̸ZϽ|)����:�Ҩ#5�k�c
�[z�����[��9�+$]5vak����_8=�MR�n<�S\���k���=-${ܜU�Kp{Ukzձ�
q"�j���׷����S[0�t�H��jRA�N��6���
��j�y��)��Fi�Cb�L,zkJU��&Fi��aLy�(�.XcM$b�M4�}h��
c0�K�0����  Y�D�Q�{��\.=��[ޣf�3B�)4��TE�3y��w'�4�U}��,��cL�y�{Z��!��o9�h�3�����gD�d���<�X���k&��#J�eNW�? �ʄ����ˑ��V�qY�c��Y�}F3�uM���=
D
H��Q���6͇�T��S��`j�Г��q�&�� �
��Q��}@q�yX�zh�e�a�f�[Æ�Q�d�Kx�l�fۑ�h����@��Mp�F�1��[}�q^�Y+�e}έ_���.$܄U;{��G5d&�]�H�LʾH�w�\�#Eu7Q$�?�DA$k9S�7�W��Kw�ٞk��������סxfE�$�\ꟼzs��

��Nk�KV�\ES�+��]�i#Δ\��_l]�نz�t�%nA�b�  +���"����W5J����SQ��I4Ǆd�U�AS��5���9-�!N3��%S���I�!�q0d����[Kp,m��dU��r@����[+I|��Y���;��-X\���y�r���R��1X�ۖ%��)���*��]J��NtW;#$���+��Z]5��yP�c�?J�e�->'�L�L�U���k�SM��Զ�%դN�S���t���z���\��������&��b3[�Lz`�cY�kfS��2����|�W*á�3R2%�7;p�jƛ*���ǔ������WV�O��R��zjI�
�dsv�l�V�'�.{�R鄽�����=�җW�]�É�;�MR�.���k����+�ZJ�;V�Ҏ=�Ȅga��Jl2E-��36�c��T ���@N7��-��M,k�x���r��V�\���u��}/F�"�]�3*/<��u��V���3i�(����1��5�#w=k���,�Yq��GZ�;���^4�iN�y`��k��#�FsT��T}���bq�Q�@y�[rSp�p��k���a1�������ƥ��uQ�]qϨ5���;��>����Q��yuoi#�[����������}@c�O��KUʝ���iJ۽��۞�j?��]ߣ�
��l���h�R�ڧ�jÞEr����p�.v���j$n��5��%�5lk�������d�V#<W%Z���T�2/��� KY1��d�6
�Rmݝ|�Z��+cIpePMs�\V����u9�5�eb$���Z�P
t�P�@Z�<?p��We�����jy���/d$��j�5[S���c�B�"�5��К�uZg"���2O�f���'�fIty�����ޣi��e=��Uy/��h�-3i�3Q�������#z}E.`��5���
a�ޮ|�Zi�>���X�
�����X���
ߩ��f���r=k�Y�Hn���Vm5�����X��ސ���� ��z�ǭd��I��z9����ǭ9f��.��t3���
�0�T��WK���4��)�`�X�k�g�3�
g�rk9A�b�^'�ζ��<RE�.j�ث���C+M��?�;4�0isY�
�*�إ��I?�k�H�]DD�*E<[H?�Ӗ�֊D�OJ��5��_w�����
uC8�pb�s�
Y��]n
3]f��^q�N�GZ촽@,c&��J���&���U�2"f�.5@�5�$�����qU�;�+�0   ��Nq ��v��&��Qsһ"�r�$ts��Ŀ���V��������/Ӟ��.���9��5I�b��^����;V�gf����.�k���g�F�G�Cv�A�Uu�M"���8�O�������in   �Vn��ƒoSS���bMc]L��k�\* �Ysko4�Y��un� E+�wHx5N��A��I&B�z˾��k��w�f���쒤��Q�q�֬�M�AN��#`��]x�D��\��ڴ�KK    � nL�Q'�d���>�;
B,�7K�3�rQ��U8���բ�����6��8�����KY�u&��f����r��qZZE�EY,��ч��qSZ�mn  \:}᚟T�^M2Y��Ğ|N����Y6����H�]��m�5h���M��Z��1`?{�u�����%哈�cꧡ�R;�Z�[A�ݵޖ�e��}m�,����ٔ�������w]΀�֮x[Y�`l/ʉ�s�G�Fa�T��LSm�H�n2{��KMj1si���G���:�UEs+2[�wE��mRM "<��?�\|����8=�+��uV5�x�t=W��P��j*�s��`�~��uY��wwG7�Gp�He��܎ⷬ�On��gB���:V_�2��a�L\qZZa��Hm��c��z����4U����J/�s\�pK�A*�ڽB�̝6����~^j�5/����^yRj{��/y-�+��wC���+YIa�i�Σ��W�+�-�Ɠ[���C�]�x��1�:���   _�͉�*ѷS��X��S�Z�;�����@>�Ԑ�L�5�j�*C�3R3�>Y��A�*�mT09j�Ψ�p⢗VRϟƸ��F��j:�
y�OTԌ��sU./�S��_
y&���ؿ�$P�Y&bI8���V���R�~ͱ<gc�{�-4X�]A�CښmW=)�;�m���Jp�#�teA�SM�U(���n�3B����!��dVƛy�q����g:��\��P�.��U�ڲd7jϽ� �շ1��s#Z�;�k����k��~k
�I��#��-���K�Vf�
�4~��+�-ң7'֠�Z��|���ZH��>��v�Y�wsM�=��)A&�}i
�����4�=is1�#O�w��h���SF��h�"4�����c=k7�i��ppF���y�ֳ��ZP��J�D_��
*�}j��nsE�pF�\�֞nk01�Gz|ĸ^L��$9���p��.[���tr�J!�
�S�9X��i�)+V���L��)�f�`�m��/�}+l��ҝ��k0�eᢏ�����ֺpSڑ�{Wb���Q��h���g�2�q�WM&�Jh)�C�vs��XakJ���#��P�� *=�%MH��q&�@��h&`�X�(
Srýe�Tn��7e��sT$��Ȫjs��C.4,C�6mX�pk�ҵ`���$�t52^ʝ�Q�ݞ���1�����$���.����n9j��b7�;�Ĝ�;t��ɨ��w�٨�̞Msʇ6�L1�$S�n��rB�ִ�APGj��Eh�箭es�A9�Y�E�[\jw/�Xp���f��V�ܰ���b� �����7��/���fA�����I'��¹�s���会@O͍�'�&�   �UIpv�
�4�Dy�R�GԖ1ߏ���Ұz+����G�K�_i���q2@F3\�Y����!(�"v�}��U��;���x�3_J����N�a%��]J�w:%k\"��7��\[��чc�WM����g�_�a��o�?α/$F�4�MJ�7ј�0��+[E�{NKi@(�b`{����J��8���E�-؏���1Щ=+���M^�u=2_'Q��S�ök��fmuV~��a�Rh:��W�$n<�<x��ky�n�¢M�uZV��'��Kr!�'�Tq��T��5�yY��D�u��ڲ|\ʳ��m�INA��V
v�&gC}
�\������B��+�e$����/q ����[�:u�����J6A��ݜWp�����w�jȶ���`�G=3�5]�B/sJY-�iT7?2��ԚU�a��.y�����D����Q�����m�}���0O��"��$
�hѰ��� ��^q�����)X���������h��X`zZ圂c�&    ��o-Z�i8e�Z۱�b@�����W6�H�v�a���9���f ���h9�t�MhB:������:�\E3DĂ��9��87QU5�9��O��vaj��Y��xoiu�9E
��ԩ��j��GjxU�����D��z�Q�juQҝ�ͅ��S�޴�) r1r��R٥Ȥ$Q���C��wt��3I�G#�ԟ8�RdR�Q��1g�z7�g����M*�r����Cڨʒ1<���������jX�T巓Һ�CP�d�v��li\��g��zWi&�aQ01�)�2�8�������c]�i*GJ��b�FW1Ř[
!���k�m%GjE�ҎFR�����G���5��d/����_AG#9�y
�i|��5�d/�E�v���8�%�(?����#����@����9!zR����Vt��)�K���F9CzS7�5�3ڗ�,z
\�.rau��[��Nt���t�?�R�d�Nu��U�q[#M���z��tQO���g!=�X��W��ڦK/j9Y) ��R����`v�~�=)r��Ndk_��u�����٩~����3������Tmg���������/l����ߣR�p�p�k��_9��G�`v���R�m�q{��N��{`�t�׸�
k�W �����D��?�?l/`���k�R�md���̟�4�h��Ən/`���hz�m���2�x��?�i�a{w_�@�� �pB�O�wڥ���س�Me7sҦ:��^z���k_B���9�8��{F��p�SI��oun�Ǫ�=�j��Oq�nw�'���֤���np�>ƭh*m5�  q^Cz�},U�D:9G��=:�>ic0�ԆY��ڼUhݠ�$��QG&��`�θ��_%�%J��I�܅��_�̇��u��Gu��A/�B+/����D-�/o�Z�2� �P�K���������rt�f�هr�E>��������T��������b+���s}�`  "U?\�*߆.���6,�ǉc��4J�QF�A~ ��-���r�����$[�)c<2.~�֭��w�MŤ��]�����b���ɪI�#d9�V�ib\�+�6�t��2Xܜ��'ѻ��d��5��N����Q���QG?vU��:խ\�����89��&�:�Լ�MAA;�������-��x(��=>���%-�Ywc������A:�I�?�MekY��d�\$hÞ@j�m�:[�����_UoOqT<+����7�1�&�<B�ڬ~A�{��h���^����qă=���o9>e9�E]�N$@INj���c��_��'�d�G5�X���ի!,P eTmo]��Po:܀��;#��3�d���jZ��n�$o���;{֔�V0�`7qY�
��v7v�d9�nGU>���%��9{���ᣐ�֢�t\|�K�s�l���B������\H����S��nϙ�a�&�=ob?�N�dޯ=M`��4㬜�֞�&�G~o#�����<�����h��?ޣ�D~͝������?�+���ޥ��i{D͝�O��7����s��/������D^͝��S������kG?x�Ƶ�ѧ�r3�  ��G���p�[?ޣ�l�~�i��    ��R��ָQ���N��?ߣ�!����Qރ*z��F��ߧ
p����΃����}E8H���n��Ү����>h�����1ښ΂�������s?�O� �θ�P�\x�y��K���M(�+;��J1\��?���{�����C�;�F��q�������w��J�|��'aHYk����n���M8���/�!)�\��{o�)�?ۢ�VuOJPSҹo�������]������x�\��1�B��oޓh:PWҝ�q\��|}�K��?�F���nZpq��W�S
Y}EV�X�W������������Ԭ�c��H�����ҹ�a�N�R"����"lC���[X�Jc���,
Ei�j��jc�+�q��ar�� 8�#�x�-�J��v�e>Uvh�]�
��b��zU�`qҷ!�J�� t���w"�k��������3����e�Ȧ1�q�S�#�GҜ�O�E��ڷk�~�W�����Jbz��t��YH��]���[v�@6�3&�<Rm�X��Pw8E��3�U��$�B@�����u°��3�'�Y\���!�O#��Xrs��4O�7H���q�I!
k��i�8�H9���
l���Ƕ�"�X���)�c��i2֛8����dVǊ���{�rDaI�b)?�.H�$�����?N�;���vW�����wG�G~q���5D��6�6��X�������,��!��f�oC�*����1�����m�>�lS�����g?��)���j
��ԕ�-�NA,�}
i�G�Ġ��`�U+�!Tc�������
�'�����J$Z�(ڇp �=
v��g�+��y����$�����9�L�֖�n۵I�;��+���#7J�{k7��pج��&I�q��z,�1�[TcҪg�wsZ8�V<���㔪�{�3g#�#rƽ]������rKt�p�}ޟ�j��amNa�Z[o4Yy�[F(N0GB>��o3���)5V��&C*�Y�m��=M6��mĶ�v�RF>j�>�P�����|����qǱ�z�#���$'��U��A#����y��剁�����Y��^�r�.�<$��뛊�68���;X��I��إ�4)}
wQ�H��(����/jpb�
'���
z� ��!���)�^���i7���K�k�N���4�}�Q�����͎���M�k�?��ئ���O�^����CG�7����N>�4��ΎA{c�0��I���k�:/��؟�S�a���2�C������SN���.F?l�+˗
&�}
v�Eܦ���9X{dq�%��ģ������e1�o�(�a�Q��_zBe����q��ci��X~�'+��zMҏZ��I�d�m��iY����n�ޓ|��Н/�i?����|�07��I�Oz�?��٦ɦ>�-F��q�M��=MjO��ڨMlW��I2=��ӄ��M�d�vU����M/�$�5$v�*Ahqҗ1/�����>����6�ҙ�n:S�'?���i�r��4�!�jb&���3J��ƭ����5B����3)�F��?��?j���3�Y��~�}*���F`ո����Cn4�uƙ�J]�G�L��i��V����bgr?+j�vqV��)�
ѭ2��U�Z�(��H���՝pؠ�Kt5��Q�P&Xr3X�2s���]X�n�+Ϭ�GM-�ef��t:m�Y�ڱ�T���P�x��>Z�Ѧ����i������4��V��h� ���z�qOHqڭ�Dz��$7b�hWSgh�e �!�C![�ֽ�����)�EtB��Z��>�u�Yx�����Es�NVb�q�~��c�����j)en  �Ey%��ݏ��q�1�-�s��9�Q��5�0�T��QD2�d8?#p~��߲�9�E'kRkY\d��ո�m�q�����.*�ϔ��Vm�-��'|5iZ��H#�Uh"i�x����3��I�m�����{T�ڻ:`Z۹Ҽ��8"�t�"B���;T9�h�em���Ho������C�Բc���ʶWh<c�i:|���R*;)Ӱ�>��a�#�u�C$jHǥe�"ƥW�<ոC�N2�Ÿ\ڒUlv��b�R
```

Currently the file which is saving inside receipts folder is corrupted.

I tried to write the raw file in the way listed below as well, but again the file is corrupted:

```
$file = $_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'invoice'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'user_' . $user_id .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'receipts'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $file_name;

$destination = $file;
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Please help where I am making a mistake ??

Comment: That should be fine. I tried this myself and got the same response. The weird characters which is returning is just the representation of the file. I don't think there is anything wrong with your code. Have you try saving the file to the specific file type (i.e. JPEG)? Good luck!

Comment: Please see the above two ways for writing the file content in a file, but I failed. ie file_put_contents and fopen. Please tell where I am making mistake. Please telll how to save this file.